# spring oauth authoritzation server: Does saving the security context to the session break the oauth2 flow?

Tags: spring, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I'm currently working on an oauth2 authorization server using spring. I would like to implement an admin dashboard for managing users. Naturally the endpoints for user management are on the auth server. To authorize a user to use the admin dashboard, they will need to log in of course, so I'm redirecting them to the /authorize endpoint when trying to access the admin dashboard. However, after logging in the spring auth server module places a session cookie in the end users browser and saves the security context to the session. Doesn't this break the oauth2 flow?

Now there is no need to request a bearer token because all the end user needs is that session ID to get access to the admin endpoints on the auth server. This seems like a security risk to me.

Should I disable saving the security context?

Comment: It's hard tell, because you've left out some details but you seem to be coalescing an oauth2 client and a resource server into a single concept in your design, and then bolting both of those onto an authorization server (which combines all 3 roles). I don't think you want to do that. You need to decide what type of client you have which will access these endpoints. Is it a REST client? Is it an OAuth2 client? Is it a browser (session-based) client/app hosted inside the auth server? Can you please update your question with that answer and some more details?

Comment: We've actually posted a much better and more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77302026/how-can-i-configure-a-spring-oauth2-auth-server-to-act-both-as-an-auth-and-resou/77303365?noredirect=1#comment136282537_77303365

Also, no, this is server will not serve as a client. This is an auth server but we want to provide some admin endpoints for managing users for example. So rather its an auth server + resource server.

The question has pretty much been solved already but feel free to take a look at it anyways.

Comment: I've read through the comments and seems you feel you have an answer. I'm glad to hear that. However, it does seem there's quite a bit of confusion still. It may help to realize that what you're doing is uncommon. An authorization server is not a client of itself, nor is it a resource server protected by itself. So accepting access tokens minted by itself should be rare. The only time this is done in OAuth2 is when the client makes a request to the user info endpoint. You should instead have a completely separate (non-oauth2) authentication for the vue.js admin app.

Comment: Don't a lot of authentication servers like keycloak for example to it the same way? For keycloaks admin api you first request a bearer token too and then attach it to the request header when making a request to an admin endpoint.

Comment: I don't work on the keycloak project so I couldn't say for sure, but it is certainly possible to use bearer tokens for an admin API. The issue is how you obtain them. You seem to suggest a user-facing authentication flow to obtain them, but admin bearer tokens would likely use the `client_credentials` grant type and be a "machine", not a user. If that's what you want to do, then you can easily add an extra filter chain that only accepts bearer tokens. However, if you want user-level access tokens, your vue.js app needs to be an OAuth2 Client or use a BFF as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens are used only for requests sent **from an OAuth2 client** to an OAuth2 resource server.

Login being a client concern, applications with `oauth2Login` are OAuth2 clients. The requests sent from a browser **to (not from) an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`** are always secured with sessions.

Requests to the dashboard application (itself if it is a MVC app or a BFF if it is a SPA or mobile app) will be secured with sessions (and CSRF protection). Only requests from the dashboard application to the users management REST API can be secured with Bearer access tokens.

Comment: I'm not talking about the oauth client placing a cookie. The point of my question is that I have several "secure" endpoints on my auth server. The auth server places a session cookie after the login. So the user with the session cookie can immediately access the resources on the auth server, circumventing the token request, regardless of what happens on the client.

Comment: How comes that the browser is sending a direct REST request to the authorization server? How comes that REST endpoints on the authorization server are secured with the same security filter-chain as the authorization ones? And also, how are  we supposed to explain what exactly is wrong in your conf when you provide no Java code, no properties and no logs? All we can do is remind some basic concepts.